# Valid way to get HibernateGridDataSource sorted by specified columns

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

The common usage of `HibernateGridDataSource` for showing table contents on page is just simple method:

```
public GridDataSource getList() {
    return new HibernateGridDataSource(session, Foo.class);
}
```

I wonder, what is the valid and beauty way to get this data source presorted by specified columns? For example, let's it would be field `date` of `Foo` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the decision for my self. Any others more convenient methods will be also appreciated.

```
    return new HibernateGridDataSource(session, Foo.class) {
        @Override
        protected void applyAdditionalConstraints(Criteria crit) {
            crit.addOrder(Order.desc("date"));
        }
    };
```